# Which chapter of the manga does Season 4 of Strike the Blood anime start in?

Tags: strike-the-blood

Strike the Blood season 4th started , but I would like to spoil myself and read more of what's coming in the manga. Which chapter should I start reading?

Which chapter of the manga does Season 4 of Strike the Blood anime start in?